# Air Android - Adapt the intent filter for receiving content from other apps

Tags: android, android-intent, air

I would like to use the [Android intent filter](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html#handling-content) for receiving content from other apps in an Air for Android app.
What do I need to enter for `.ui.MyActivity`?

This is from the Android documentation:

> When another application tries to share any of these things by
>   constructing an intent and passing it to startActivity(), your
>   application will be listed as an option in the intent chooser. If the
>   user selects your application, the corresponding activity
>   (.ui.MyActivity in the example above) will be started. It is then up
>   to you to handle the content appropriately within your code and UI.

```
<activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" >
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I'm using Adobe Air 3.6 and Flash CS 6.
Thank you. Uli